# Python Stack Overflow with tkinter and threading

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, stack-overflow

I have a problem about python stack overflow. I am writing an application with python using Tkinter and 4 other threads. but the problem is that after an hour of working, i get the stack overflow error and the app crashes. my questions:

1. May the "after" method in Tkinter affect the system and makes the stack overflow problem? I have to use it every 0.5 seconds to update my GUI.
2. May the variables (there are lots of variables) affect the stack memory? do i need to delete (del) them?
3. Is there any way to know specially which thread and function made the overflow? because i have a recursive function in one of the threads.

Thanks!

```
class App(): 
def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
    notebook=ttk.Notebook(master,width=800,height=480)
    frame1=ttk.Frame(notebook,style='TNotebook')
    frame2=ttk.Frame(notebook,style='TNotebook')
    frame3=ttk.Frame(notebook,style='TNotebook')
    frame4=ttk.Frame(notebook,style='TNotebook')
    notebook.add(frame1,text='p1')
    notebook.add(frame2,text='p2')
    notebook.add(frame3,text='p3')
    notebook.add(frame4,text='p4')
    notebook.pack()

    self.varopt34=StringVar(master)
    self.varopt34.set(datashowgui[27].strip())
    self.opt34=OptionMenu(frame3,self.varopt34,'0','1')
    self.opt34.config(background="gray80",font="Harabara",width=1,height=1,highlightbackground="white",activebackground="gray80",fg="white")
    self.opt34.place(x=370,y=220) 

    varopt1=StringVar(master)
    varopt1.set(fglines[5])
    opt1=OptionMenu(frame4,varopt1,id1,id2,id3,id4,id5,command=self.forganize1)
    opt1.place(x=150,y=18)
    opt1.config(background="gray80",font="Harabara",width=11,height=2,highlightbackground="white",activebackground="gray80",fg="white")

    tkButtonSave=tk.Button(frame3,image=clockimage16,text="Save Settings and Reboot",compound=CENTER,command=self.savesettings,bg="white",highlightbackground="white",activebackground="white",fg="white",font=("Harabara",15),width=250,height=20)
    tkButtonSave.place(x=500,y=320)

    tkButtonReset=tk.Button(frame4,image=clockimage16,text="Reset Sensors and Reboot",compound=CENTER,command=self.resetsensors,bg="white",highlightbackground="white",activebackground="white",fg="white",font=("Harabara",15),width=250,height=20)
    tkButtonReset.place(x=500,y=320)

    tkButtonQuit=tk.Button(master,image=clockimage16,text="Quit",compound=CENTER,command=self.quitwindow,bg="white",highlightbackground="white",activebackground="white",fg="white",font=("Harabara",20),width=100,height=20)
    tkButtonQuit.place(x=600,y=420)

    self.update_reading()


def savesettings(self):
    f=open("tempconfigreference.txt","r")
    datasaveref=f.readlines()
    f.close()
    f=open("tempconfig.txt","w+")
    f.writelines(datasaveref)
    f.close()    


def quitwindow(self):       
    self.master.destroy() 

def resetsensors(self):
    f=open("temps.txt","r")
    lines=f.readlines()
    f.close()
    f=open("organizedtemps.txt","w+")
    f.writelines(lines)
    f.close()


def savesensors(self):
    #print('savesensorsisrunning')
    organizetemp.dosave()    
    #&self.after(100 , savesensors)       


def update_reading(self):
    now=datetime.now()
    nowpersian=jalali.Gregorian(now.year,now.month,now.day).persian_tuple()
    self.master.after(580 , self.update_reading)
    self.master.after(850 , self.savesensors)
def display(threadName):

#print (threadName)
root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

yes of course, this is a sample code and abstract of one of the threads which controls the GUI.
Here is the thread  which have the recursive function (it is trimmed to be easy to read):

```
def startcommunicate(thread_name):
def cpu_temp():
    htot1=open("finaltemps.txt","r")
    linesorganized=htot1.readlines()
    htot1.close()
    if linesorganized:
        cpu_temp=linesorganized[0]
    else:
        cpu_temp=0
    return cpu_temp
try:
    run (host='169.254.176.82', port=80, quiet=True)
except:
    time.sleep(5)
    startcommunicate('Thread-1')
```

Comment: How are you using after? There should not be a problem with the after method if you are simply update a label or entry field. We would need to see some testable example of your code to prove a good answer. Please read and provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: can you show the actual error message?

Comment: yes of course,"fatal python error cannot recover from stackoverflow". I am working on an embedded device and i wonder why i dont get recursion error while i have not set it to a high limit!?

Comment: Have you tried to run simple print statements in each thread to see what the last thread was that ran when the error happened?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
It was the "startcommunicate" recursively called function.
But I should find a better way to write the mentioned thread (Maybe using a while loop). Ready to get any help!
Thanks.